# Express resolves to an unused l-value

Tags: ios, swift

What am I doing wrong?

```
@IBOutlet weak var takenPhoto: UIImageView!    
var imageBlock = false

   if !imageBlock {
        takenPhoto.isHidden
    }
```

I'm receiving such error: Express resolves to an unused l-value on takenPhoto.isHidden

Comment: Are you trying to hide `takenPhoto`?

Comment: yes, exactly @vacawama

Comment: `takenPhoto.isHidden = true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *l-value* refers to a storage location.  In your case, you have a line of code that mentions `takenPhoto.isHidden`, but you're not assigning anything to it which is why you get the error message.

To hide `takenPhoto`, set the value to `true`:

```
takenPhoto.isHidden = true
```